# Derivation of the exit velocity of water through a hole by force analysis at hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

As it is the setup with Torricelli's law, consider a hole (of negligible height difference) of area A at a height of h from the top of a cylinder filled with a non-viscous liquid of density $\rho$.

Torricelli's law tells us that the exit velocity of the water through the hole is $v_{exit} = \sqrt{2gh}$.

I have tried to derive it in the following way, which seems to be erroneous, but I can't find the mistake:

At a height h from the surface, the pressure of the upper fluid layers is $P = \rho g h$. We can consider a small "packet" of mass $dm$ near the hole (having the same cross-sectional area A) Then,

$P = F/A$, or $F = PA$ (F is the force exerted on the small packet of mass).

We consider a small instant of time $dt$, during which the small mass packet gains a velocity $v_{exit}$ due to the acceleration. Since $dm$ was initially at rest:

$F = dm* \frac{v_{exit}}{dt}$.

We can express the flow rate of the mass packet of the fluid as:

Flow rate = $A*v_{exit}$

Hence, in an infinitesimal time dt, the amount of fluid that flows through A is:

$dV = A*v_{exit}*dt$
$\implies dm = \rho*A*v_{exit}*dt$

Putting everything together:

$F = dm* \frac{v_{exit}}{dt} = (\rho*A*v_{exit}*dt) * \frac{v_{exit}}{dt} = \rho*A*v_{exit}^2$

So,

$\rho*A*v_{exit}^2 = PA = \rho g h A$

$\implies v_{exit}^2 = gh$

Thus,
$v_{exit} = \sqrt{gh}$

**Where's the missing factor of $\sqrt{2}$ ?**

(I am aware of the derivation using Bernoulli's principle, but my question is rather about the error in my derivation).

Comment: Have you tried writing down the assumptions of Toricelli and Bernoulli's law?/ Have you read pre-existing discussions about the same on thi ssite?

Comment: [Wikipedia is a good place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law)

Comment: Well, Bernoulli assumes that the fluid is incompressible (which was assumed, otherwise the density of the fluid under pressure won't be the same). And for Torricelli, I don't see how the horizontal cross-section of the cylinder is relevant in my derivation. Could you provide any more insights? Thank you for your time! (Yes, I have gone through some of the previous discussions on this topic on Physics Stackexchange, but I have not seen any questions involving the inconsistency of the derivation I posted).

Comment: We don't care about the velocity it gains near the exit. It already gained most of the velocity as it flew down to the exit from the bulk of the liquid. The approach you are using has no conceptual basis

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you meant by "as it flew down to the exit from the bulk of the liquid"?

Comment: Imagine the mass packet moving down from maybe the top of the fluid bulk into the exit point. It was falling under gravity, and hence was gaining energy. This energy corresponds to exit velocity. The exit velocity has nothing to do with what the energy gained exactly about the exit point is.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the particles are at rest at start but bernoulli's derivation assumes liquid is flowing from the surface of liquid to the exit point (the h is the height between surface and exit point) so you have used "h" and also assumed initial velocity to be 0

Comment: Any disk of water passing the hole gets an "impulse", Latin, that is a hit by a hammer, that changes its "momentum", Latin, that is the transfer of substance in a short time. 

Only in the case, that the pressure is provided by water in a pipe, vessel or a dam, the kinetic energy by the bottom pressure force has to be equal to the potential energy for a lift to the free surface (in order to prevent experiments on a perpetuum mobile).